# Using the Girsanov theorem to construct a solution to an SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose that $B$ is a standard Brownian motion and $b$ is a bounded, measurable function. Using the Girsanov theorem, construct a solution to the SDE $$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+dB_t.$$

I really don't know where to start with this, as I'm not sure how a change of measure could be used for a solution. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hint : Find  a change of measure using Girsanov theorem that allows you to get rid of the drift term.

Comment: The book *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* by Karatzas and Shreve is one possible text book where one could learn this from.

Comment: Please update you question with your attempts once you've studied the hints by TheBridge and Kurt above.